# How to get multiple input data in array or empty?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this contact person form:
[image: contact person form]

If the contact form input field does not have any value then set the `$contact_person` variable to empty, if the contact form input field has a value then set the `$contact_person` variable as a multidimensional array.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
$contact_person = array();
if(isset($_POST['contact-name'])){

    $contact_phone = $_POST['contact-phone'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact-email'];
    $contact_designation = $_POST['contact-designation'];

    foreach($_POST['contact-name'] as $key => $value) {
        $contact_person[] = [
            'contact_name' => $value,
            'contact_phone' => $contact_phone[$key],
            'contact_email' => $contact_email[$key],
            'contact_designation' => $contact_designation[$key]
        ];
    }

}

if(count($contact_person)>0){
    print_r($contact_person);
}
else{
    $contact_person = 'empty';
}
```

When I submit button with all fields then I got below responnse: that's fine

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [contact_name] => abc [contact_phone] => 9876543210 [contact_email] => abc@gmail.com [contact_designation] => developer ) [1] => Array ( [contact_name] => xyz [contact_phone] => 9876543210 [contact_email] => xyz@gmail.com [contact_designation] => developer ) )
```

But when I submit button with empty field then I get response below: that's not fine

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [contact_name] => [contact_phone] => [contact_email] => [contact_designation] => ) [1] => Array ( [contact_name] => [contact_phone] => [contact_email] => [contact_designation] => ) )
```

So, when all field is empty then I want **empty** response.

Comment: Do this double checking : `if(isset($_POST['contact-name']) && !empty($_POST['contact-name'])){` I think it should work

Comment: This boils down to a simple `if` condition which you should place in the loop. Where did you get stuck on this?

Comment: @Kiji_T No need for `isset` when using `empty`, it will check if the variable is set. Plus, as I mentioned under the answer already, I feel this is the wrong place for the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `! empty($value)` condition inside the foreach loop to check the value is not empty

Right now, whats happening is when user enter button with empty fields/value, on **POST** request, at backend PHP is getting this key set but it's values are empty.

Just to ensure `$_POST` is set, if the html form is calling **Self**

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
```

and checking value is not empty inside the loop

```
foreach($_POST['contact-name'] as $key => $value) {
    if (! empty($value) {
        $contact_person[] = [
            'contact_name' => $value,
            'contact_phone' => $contact_phone[$key],
            'contact_email' => $contact_email[$key],
            'contact_designation' => $contact_designation[$key]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `isset` anymore when you use `!empty`, it will check if the variable is set.

Comment: Aside from that, I feel this is the wrong place for the condition. `$_POST['contact-name']` is an array and won't be considered empty even if it has nothing but empty strings inside it.

Comment: I agree, this is the wrong place for the condition, it should be inside the foreach loop